# Themes in $HOME/.themes don't load all config as /usr/share/themes

Tags: themes

I downloaded a theme and put it in `$HOME/.themes` and I noticed that some apps didn't pick-up the theme. I moved the same files to `/usr/share/themes` and now the same app has the theme. Shouldn't the `$HOME/.themes` load all config for my user?

Edit 1:
Theme: Yaru (built from source https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru)
App: Synaptic (`sudo apt install synaptic`)
I do have `User Themes` extension, it helped to configure Calendar, Notifications, Right-click menu, but not Synaptic.

Edit 2:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Do you have this gnome-shell extension installed? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/

Comment: What apps work, which don't? What version of Ubuntu is this? What theme is this? Fussy questions can only yield fuzzy answers.

Comment: Hi @vanadium , fair questions, I have edited my question.

Comment: Hi @heynnema : yes, I do have User Themes extension, it helped to configure Calendar, Notifications, Right-click menu, but not Synaptic.

Comment: What is the specific version of your system? `lsb_release -a` in the terminal can provide this information. Are there other apps besides synaptic that do not pick up the theme?

Comment: Hi @vanadium Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS focal. I did not notice other apps. The moment I saw that synaptic didn't pick-up the colors, I started looking for a solution and didn't open other apps until it was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't the $HOME/.themes load all config for my user?

Yes, for your user.

However, when you run Synaptic, you provide a password. The app then runs as user `root`. Systemwide themes in `/usr/share/themes` continue to be found, but `$HOME/.themes` now became `/root/.themes`.

Comment: Sure, makes sense! So, any app run as root won't pick-up the $HOME/.themes . Thank you